# Unknown Error from SBT console for dispatch-Http Get request

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-dispatch

I m doing simple Http GET request by using dispatch library in SBT.

My Code:

```
def getReq(){

   val svc = url(GlobalObjects.BASE_GET_REQUEST_URL);
    val response : Future[String] = Http(svc OK as.String)

    response onComplete {
      case Success(content) => {
        println("Successful response" + content)
      }
      case Failure(t) => {
        println("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
      }
    }

}
}
```

When I run from SBT console it shows the following unKnown Error. Someone has any idea what is wrong here?

```
[error] (run-main) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ObjectRef.zero()Ls
cala/runtime/ObjectRef;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ObjectRef.zero()Lscala/runtime/Object
Ref;
        at dispatch.InternalDefaults$SbtProcessDefaults$.builder(defaults.scala)

        at dispatch.InternalDefaults$.client(defaults.scala:32)
        at dispatch.Http$.<init>(execution.scala:30)
        at dispatch.Http$.<clinit>(execution.scala)
        at com.czechscala.blank.User.getReq(User.scala:30)
        at com.czechscala.blank.Hello$.main(Hello.scala:81)
        at com.czechscala.blank.Hello.main(Hello.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last compile:run' for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last compile:run' for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed May 24, 2015 9:00:58 PM
```

In case I am posting my build.sbt as well.

my build.sbt:

```
name := "blank"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
    "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "1.9.1" % "test"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.1.2"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch" % "0.8.10"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-actors" % "2.10.2"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.8.10"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-futures" % "0.8.10"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-nio" % "0.8.10"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.6.4",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.6.4"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-core" % "3.2.10",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.10",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.10",
  "net.databinder" %% "unfiltered-netty" % "0.8.0" % "test",
  "net.databinder.dispatch" % "dispatch-json4s-native_2.11" % "0.11.1"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.argonaut" %% "argonaut" % "6.0.4"  
)

initialCommands := "import dispatch._"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the same issue as with your other question.

net.databinder.dispatch is using 2.11 instead 2.10.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working now. I changed my version.